# Disable jQuery dialog on refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, page-refresh

I have a jQuery Dialog set to `autoOpen:true`.

Thus it pops up on page load. The `dialog` contains two buttons

one closes it, the other opens a `form`,

, when I submit the form, I have set a redirect to the same page.

I would rather this `dialog' does not appear again when the redirect (kind of refresh) happens.

I have tried using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as below:

```
   var ref_url = $('#referring_url').val();
   var cur_url = $('#current_url').val();
   var refresher = true;

   if(ref_url = cur_url)
      refresher = false;
   else
      refresher = true;
```

I have set the `dialog` `autoOpen` value to `refresher`

and then to parse the uri values from php i have used the hidden input boxes below:

```
<input id="referring_url" name="referring_url" id="referring_url" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" />

<input id="current_url" name="current_url" id="current_url" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
```

Comment: As a general architecture advice why not having a look if you can submit the form via AJAX and therefore avoid refreshing the website at all?

Comment: Thanks @yoshi , definitely would work. I am just not that well versed with AJAX, planning to learn though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using assignment in the if expression.

`if(ref_url = cur_url){` this statement should be `if(ref_url == cur_url){`

Comment: Or even better `===`, if you dont need the type conversion.

Comment: And the `else` condition is unnecessary. The `refresher` value is `true` in var declaration

Comment: @sQve Thanks, but what do you mean by type conversion?

Comment: @JorgeLoureiro Thanks, true, totally unnecessary.

Comment: @watkib `==` type converts before it does a check, so `123 == "123"` is **true**, `123 === "123"` is **false** but it is **true** if the type is the same eg. `"123" === "123"`... Hope this explains it a bit.